# using would in past in the past

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I was reading wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greece#Government_and_law) and saw this sencence:

> Through each stage more power would have been transferred to the aristocracy as a whole, and away from a single individual.

1. I can't understand why is there was used word "would".
   The sentence meaning about what is really had been but not about "would" had been.
2. Why is using "have been" here  but not "had been"? Article tells about past in the past is not it?

Comment: The author says "It is unclear exactly how this change occurred", so what follows is only speculation about what happened. _Would have been_ is correct for the past conditional, not _would had been_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. I see. Thank you!